# Prolog unify Lists inside a list

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to define a relation over lists...

```
?- matrix_items([[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]],Rs).
Rs = [a,b,c,d,e,f].                        % expected result
```

So far, I was able to do something like this; unfortunately it doesn't add up all the elements:

```
sift([],_).                                              
sift([H|T],[H|Result]) :-
   create(H,Result),
   sift(H,Result). 

create([],_).
create([H|T],[H|R]) :- 
   create(T,R).
```

Hope hear from you soon.

Comment: The `flatten/2` built-in might have the behaviour you seem to want - it might be implemented already in the PROLOG interpreter you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. I've changed the name of the predicate to flatten_l as unify has other connotations in Prolog:

```
flatten_l([H|T], FL):-
  flatten_l([H|T], [], FL).

flatten_l([], FL, FL):- !.
flatten_l([H|T], ML, FL):-
  flatten_l(T, ML, NL),
  !,
  flatten_l(H, NL, FL).
flatten_l(X, FL, [X|FL]).
```

Note also that this predicate will give you a stack overflow error if the first argument is uninstantiated...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collapse all of the lists (even sub-lists), you can use `flatten/2`.

If you only want to collapse a single level, then the following should work:

```
unify([], []).
unify([X|Xs], Ret) :- unify(Xs, Rs), append(X, Rs, Ret).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SWI-pl, you can call `flatten/2` to flatten all levels of nesting or `append/2` to flatten only one level.